# NodeJS mongoDB like query and sorting result which should start with that query string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am facing one issue. I am using NodeJS and MongoDB, I want to use like query with sorting results like below:

Suppose I have below some examples data:

```
Abdominal Cramp
Agraphia
Afebrile
Cyclic Fever
Fever
High Fever
Continuous Fever
```

Now, I am trying to search for "fe" . The result should work like all data which contains "fe" and order should start with "fe". Like,

```
Fever
Afebrile
Continuous Fever
Cyclic Fever
High Fever
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are defining a custom sort. To do so, the typical approach is to add a new field which is generated based on your custom sort criteria. In this case that custom criteria is that words which are prefixed with the regex should come first, followed by the rest in alphabetical order.

This seems to satisfy that request with the sample data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      val: {
        $regex: "fe",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      prefix: {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$val",
              "regex": "^fe",
              "options": "i"
            }
          },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      prefix: -1,
      val: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      prefix: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gngYYNe5pP3).

My word of caution is that case insensitive regex matching cannot use indexes efficiently. You may wish to look into other approaches for the text searching portion of your query if it is the main thing that is providing selectivity.